# Dynamically change/assign ui resizable instance on already loaded DOM elements

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to dynamically assign a different instance of jQuery-UI's resizable after the DOM has loaded.

I basically want to assign a fixed aspectRatio of true or false depending on certain factors. When I request a new resizable instance, it does not seem to be updating.

The selectors used to assign resizable() are also dynamically created after DOM loads.

Here is a simplified example of my code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.lyr').addClass('loose');
    $('.lyr2').addClass('fixed');

$('#change').bind( 'click', function() {

    if( $('.lyr, .lyr2').hasClass('loose') ) {

        $('.lyr, .lyr2').addClass('fixed').removeClass('loose');

        $('#status').html('changed to fixed');

        $('.lyr, .lyr2').resizable({
            aspectRatio: true,
            handles: 'all'
        });

    } else {

        $('.lyr, .lyr2').addClass('loose').removeClass('fixed');    

        $('#status').html('changed to loose');

        $('.lyr, .lyr2').addClass('fixed'); 

    }

});

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='change' value='change'>

<div id="canvas">
    <p>Resizable items</p>
    <div class='lyr'></div>
    <div class='lyr2'></div>

</div>
```

Here is a running example: http://digitaloutback.co.uk/resizable-eg/ (press 'change' to assign initial resizable)

I have also used 'live' and 'livequery' plugin in place of 'bind' so I'm not sure what the root of the problem could be..

**Found the solution**

The answer was right in front of me in jQuery UI documentation:

resizable('destroy') before re-assigning it.

```
$('.lyr, .lyr2').resizable('destroy').resizable()..
```

Comment: Solution found and added to question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me in jQuery UI documentation:

resizable('destroy') before re-assigning it.

```
$('.lyr, .lyr2').resizable('destroy').resizable()..
```